# Postgres update row and return original under high contention

Tags: postgresql, locking

I see this from pg badger: error waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple

My query:

```
with old_values as (
    select * from info where id = $1 for update
)
new_values as (
    insert into info (id, data) values $1, $2
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT info_pkey DO UPDATE
    set data = $2
)
select * from old_values
```

It seems like we should only be getting 1 query at a time per primary key.
We have over 2k records / pk's with almost no new inserts.
We have lots of queries updating the data fields in the table.
Is there a way to improve this and/or avoid locks?
It's fine if it skips the update due to another query updating the same row at the same time.
I'd can't avoid getting the old values back.
Thanks

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? I would suggest reading [Locking clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) and [Row level locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS).  Basically you locked all the rows with `id` of `$1`, then tried to update them. Why not just run the `ON CONFLICT` query by itself?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm trying to reduce the lock contention so queries don't wait, or to jmprove performance some other way for this. I don't just run on conflict by itself because we need to return the old values.
For update should prevent other transactions from locking that row, from what I understand, which had at some point seemed to help things, maybe by reducing lock contention.  Are you suggesting I just remove that part?
There might actually be an insert sometimes.

Comment: And the solution was to add more lock contention with `FOR UPDATE`, not seeing that as helpful. Also you are locking all rows with `id = $1` and only inserting a single row.  Why not do the `SELECT`(w/o FOR UPDATE) using the same values as the `INSERT`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver How does for update add more lock contention? Doesn't it lock the same thing that the insert would anyway, and make the insert not have to lock again?
I am not sure what you mean by "SELECT(w/o FOR UPDATE) using the same values as the INSERT"  What are you suggesting, that would get me the original row values for that pk?

Comment: The `SELECT` and the `INSERT` are two different operations, they will each acquire  a lock or locks. Pretty sure that is where `error waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple` is coming from.

Comment: "FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE or SELECT FOR KEY SHARE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends;"

That looks to me like it locks the row for the whole transaction. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Believe what you want to believe. Try it w/o the `FOR UPDATE`.